# Shooting Compound bow on a Crossbow Range?

Tags: archery

The archery range near my place has two areas. One for Compound/Traditional bows and one for compound bows. The crossbow range has a tower for practicing shooting from elevation. When it's empty and not occupied by crossbowers, I'd like to try shooting from that tower instead.

My only concern is respect for the equipment on the ranges. Are there any issues with shooting crossbow targets with a compound? e.g. am I going to damage the targets shooting my compound on crossbow targets?

Comment: Could you clarify this question, please? As it's currently worded, you say they have areas for "Compound/Traditional bows and one for compound bows", but in the next sentence talk about "the crossbow range". Perhaps just a little confusion with the labels?

Answer (score 2):

First, when in doubt ask an employee not a stranger on the internet. Second, I'd say without explicit permission you should never shoot a compound bow or crossbow at a traditional bow target, details below.

Compound bows and crossbows generally need their own special targets which are much more dense and heavy than a normal bow target would require. They can shoot clean through some types of traditional targets which can be dangerous depending on the range setup. (IE going straight through and ricocheting dangerously back towards people).

The fact that they have a compound/traditional range implies they use targets where it wouldn't be an issue, however your question wording is confusing. You mention two areas, but three types of weapons, crossbow, compound bow, and traditional bow. If they had a range for traditional only I would definitely not use a compound bow or crossbow there.